# Can we log a SQL query having bind parameters in node-oracledb?

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

```js
const query = `INSERT INTO countries VALUES (:country_id, :country_name)`;
try {
    const result = await connection.execute(query, { country_id: 90, country_name: "Tonga" });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`error while executing: ${query}`);
}
```

Is there any way to log the `query` along with the bind parameters data
so that I can log `INSERT INTO countries VALUES (90, "Tonga")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found a package known as [bind-sql-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bind-sql-string) which has `queryBindToString` method that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's currently no builtin option to do that, but according to the docs you could create a wrapper around the `execute` function and log the actual query there. From the [docs](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#tracing-bind-values):

> Sometimes it is useful to trace the bind data values that have been
> used when executing statements. Several methods are available.
>
> In the Oracle Database, the view V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE can capture bind
> information. Tracing with Oracle Database’s
> DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE() may also be useful.
>
> You can also write your own wrapper around execute() and log any
> parameters.

Comment: `A wrapper to log any parameters` will only log the bind variables right? but that won't be much useful if something goes wrong and someone wants to debug the query with a huge set of bind variables, I think regex might solve this.